# add all blog posts to folder

Tags: custom-post-types, posts, permalinks

I want to add all the blog posts to the /blogs/the-post-name type structure. I can do this through the permalinks settings  with:

`/blogs/%postname%/`

but this also affects custom post types resulting in a

`/blogs/custom-post-type/the-custom-post-type-name`

How can i add all posts into the blogs folder without adding all my custom post types into the blogs folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When registering the custom post types, set `with_front` to `false`:

```
register_post_type(
    'my_post_type',
    [
        // ...etc.
        'rewrite' => [
            'with_front' => false,
        ],
    ]
);
```

The post type URL will then not include anything extra you've added in the Permalinks settings.

Comment: worked perfectly thanks Jacob.